# Incorrect syntax near ';'. in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run a simple query as below, not sure why it's throwing incorrect syntax error. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Statement:

```
SELECT MAX(mycount)
FROM (SELECT COUNT (order_id) AS mycount FROM [sales].[orders] GROUP BY [order_id]);
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need an alias for the sub-query:

```
SELECT MAX(mycount)
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT (order_id) AS mycount 
   FROM [sales].[orders] 
   GROUP BY [order_id]
) t;
```